# Using Lagom service client fails because of missing implementation

Tags: java, lagom

I am trying to use a Lagom REST service using the Lagom provided LagomClientFactory from a legacy Java application.

```
LagomClientFactory clientFactory = 
   LagomClientFactory.create("legacy-system", LagomClient.class.getClassLoader());
DeviceDetectionService serviceClient =
   clientFactory.createDevClient(DeviceDetectionService.class, URI.create("http://localhost:8000"));
```

This fails with **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to load services that don't implement Service**

I added the Lagom Java Client and the API of the service as a dependeny:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
  <artifactId>lagom-javadsl-integration-client_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example.wd</groupId>
  <artifactId>wt-wd-device-detection-api_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Actually I don't understand why the client is looking for an implementation of the service?

Comment: Hi @christianonline, is it possible that `DeviceDetectionService` doesn't `implements Service`? Even if `DeviceDetectionService` is an interface and has a default method called `descriptor`, it _has to_ `implements Service`. See https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/e53bda5fd2f83aaa4cd639c9ad27d6053ede812f/service/javadsl/client/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/lagom/internal/javadsl/client/ServiceClientLoader.scala#L21

Comment: Also, is your service a Scala or Java service descriptor?

Comment: The actual service is implemented in Scala. `trait DeviceDetectionService extends Service`

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to use a Lagom service trait written in Scala from a client implemented in Java.

The best workaround available at this point is to provide duplicate service API artifact in both Java and Scala.